# Show if theory T is ∀∃-axiomatizable, then T has an existentially closed model.

Tags: logic, model-theory, quantifiers

**Setting**

Definition $\mathcal{M} \models T$ is existentially closed if whenever $\mathcal{N} \models T$, $\mathcal{N} \supseteq \mathcal{M}$, and $\mathcal{N}\models \exists \bar{v} \phi(\bar{v},\bar{a})$, where $\bar{a} \in \mathbb{M}$ and $\phi$ is quantifier free, then $\mathcal{M} \models \exists \bar{v} \phi(\bar{v},\bar{a})$.

1. I would like to show that if T is $\forall\exists$-axiomatizable,, then T has an existentially closed model.
2. From now on we assume that if $\mathcal M \models T$, then there is $\mathcal N \supseteq \mathcal M$ existentially closed with $|\mathbb{N}| = |\mathbb{M}| + |\mathcal L| + \aleph_o$. 
   Suppose that T has an infinite nonexistentially closed model, then I want to prove T has a nonexistentially closed model of cardinality $\kappa$ for any infinite cardinal $\kappa \ge |\mathcal{L}|$.
3. Finally, I would like to show that if T is $\kappa$-catagorical for some infinite $\kappa \ge |\mathcal{L}|$ and axiomatized by $\forall\exists$-sentences, then all models of T are existentially closed.

Comment: The key lemma for this is one you mentioned in another question: if $T$ has an AE axiomatization then the class of models of $T$ is closed under taking unions of chains of models of $T$.  So the next step is to verify a lemma: if you have just *one* formula $(\exists \bar v)\phi(\bar v, \bar a)$ which is consistent with $\text{Diag}(M)$  then there is an $M'$ satisfying that formula with $M \subseteq M'$. Then apply this lemma repeatedly to get a chain of nested models, and take the limit.

Comment: @CarlMummert could you elaborate on what "taking the limit" means?

Comment: Taking the union of the chain of models. This is one example of the concept of 'direct limit' in category theory (it's a somewhat trivial example, but it is a direct limit).

Comment: @Carl are you assuming there is such a formula (∃v)ϕ(v,a) so that $Diag(M) \models (∃v)ϕ(v,a)$? Because if there is, wouldn't any extension of $M$ (you called it M') also satisfy the formula since the witness to the $\exists$ is contained in $M'$? Or am I showing that there is this formula (∃v)ϕ(v,a)?

Comment: @CarlMummert adding to what I previously said, isn't it true that $\mathcal M \models \pmb{T} \Rightarrow \mathcal M \models \forall \bar{w} \exists \bar{v} \phi(\bar{v},\bar{w}) \Rightarrow \mathcal M \models \exists \bar{v} \phi(\bar{v},\bar{a}) \text{  for every $\bar{a} \in \mathbb{M}$}$? And just to summarize you're saying we want a chain $M_1,M_2,\ldots$ where $M_{i+1} \models T_{i} \cup diag_{\exists}(M_i)$ correct?

Comment: $M$ has a set of AE axioms. That does not mean that it satisfies every existential sentence, e.g. it does not satisfy $(\exists x)[x \not = x]$. The point of being existentially closed is that the model satisfies every *consistent* existential sentence.

Comment: @Carl thank you for the clear up. May I ask you how I might go about proving 2. and 3.?

Comment: 2 follows directly from the Lowenheim-Skolem theorem. Once you have 1, you can get 3 from there - 2 may give some inspiration.